# cmake finding older libpng library even though brew installs latest

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew, github-actions

I have a Github workflow that requires version 1.16 of libpng. However, on osx,
cmake Find finds an older version 1.14 of the library

```
Run brew install libpng 
Warning: libpng 1.6.37 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.6.37, run:

....

-- Found PNG: /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib (found version "1.4.12") 
-- The system seems to have a libpnb available, it will be used to support PNG files
```

Any ideas on how to make cmake find the brew version ?

Comment: You may try to set environment variable [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) to the directory which is used as installation prefix by brew. So this directory will searched before others. (You need to perform clean configuration of your project for force CMake to re-search the library).

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev. If you put this as an answer, I will mark as correct.